# Как проверить статус оплаты Яндекс Кассы?

Tags: php, яндекс-касса

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сайт на **modx revo**. На сайте есть форма оплаты, при сабмите формы идет редирект на php файл кассы где открываю сессию, проверяю поля, пишу id и ключ магазина и так далее.

1) Получается при сабмите формы юзер редиректится на страницу Яндекс кассы . Оплачивает.

2) Далее я создал **сниппет**, который проверяет статус оплаты.

3) Далее я создал две страницы в админке (успешная оплата и неуспешная оплата). На странице НЕ успешной оплаты отдается голый текст типа "Неудачно, пробуй снова". На странице УСПЕШНОЙ оплаты текст "спасибо..." и ниже форма для регистрации этого юзера в системе Modx.

4) Как юзер приходит на страницу успешной/неуспешной оплаты - когда его редиректнуло на **яндексовскую** страницу кассы (*money.yandex.ru/payments/checkout/confirmation?orderId=...*), то можно сразу кликнуть на кнопку "вернуться в магазин", и если он не оплатил, то попадет на страницу "НЕудачная оплата". Если он оплатил, то перейдет на страницу "УДАЧНАЯ оплата" и тут продолжит свою регистрацию.

Так как не все знают, что нужно тыкнуть на "**вернуться в магазин**" после совершения оплаты, то получается что человек оплатил, но не зарегистрировался на сайте. Потом звонит и кидает претензии. Приходится проверять оплату и регать его вручную.

**Вопрос** - можно ли проверить статус оплаты на странице самой кассы сразу после совершения оплаты, а не по клику на "вернуться в магазин". Хочу, используя modx api, регать юзера программно, так как сохраняю в куки введенные им данные в поля в форме оплаты.

Answer (score 0):

В настройках яндекс кассы, Параметры для платежей, ты можешь указать shopSuccessUrl, куда будет слаться запрос при успешной оплате. Обычная страница php на твоём сайте, там пиши, что тебе надо.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, гляну. Получается мне тупо указать урл? В итоге если статус оплаты завершен успешно, то касса редиректит юзра на указанный мною урл, так?

Comment: нет, не редиректится. просто отправляется запрос на указанный адрес, с указанными тобой параметрами. и ты можешь запустить нужый код для работы с базой